# Umbraco logged in user id

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I'd like to show the user id of the currently logged in user : I can get their name

```
// logged in?
            var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            var ticket = wrapper.GetUmbracoAuthTicket();
            isLoggedIn = 0;
            sessionId = "";
            if (ticket!=null){
                if(ticket.GetRemainingAuthSeconds() > 0){
                    isLoggedIn = 1;
                }
                loggedInUsername = ticket.Name.ToString();
                sessionId = wrapper.Session.SessionID.ToString();
            }else{
                loggedInUsername = "";
            }
```

But I'd also like to get their user id so that I can store extra user into in a separate database and look it up on the page.

I did try

```
@Umbraco.GetCurrentUmbracoUser().Id
```

but I think that's from an older version of Umbraco as it crashed Umbraco 7.4

Answer (score 0):

`GetCurrentUmbracoUser` only returns a user if there is one logged in. If there isn't it will throw a null exception when you try to access the id.